# Can anyone suggest well written books for learning basic statistics/ probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning

I'm in final year high-school, (which is grade 13 where I live), and, as the title suggests, I'm seeking a book which introduces statistic/ probability with little prerequisites other than mastery of basic arithmetic and a good command and understanding of basic Algebra.

I will be self studying this, so ideally, the book should elucidate rather well written explanations for basic statistical notions.

Comment: You could look for a book of Schaum's collection..There are at least two concerning probability and statistics (but I don't recall the titles)..

Comment: I haven't read it, but [The Cartoon Guide to Statistics](https://www.amazon.com/Cartoon-Guide-Statistics-Larry-Gonick/dp/0062731025) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think Freedman, et al., is what you're looking for:

[https://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Fourth-David-Freedman-ebook/dp/B00SLB5Q72](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SLB5Q72)

It's elementary, has good, intuitive explanations, and covers all the basic topics.   I've taught out of this text several times, and I've never had any 
major problems with it.